# Getting Json error while using @variable()@ matcher

Tags: citrus-framework

I have a scenario where particular response data has to be used in the next request.
I used `payload("{\"alarmName\":\"@variable('apiVersion')@\"}")` But the execution is failing with exception. Below is the exception message.

```
{"__v":0,"minVal":18,"alarmName":"TempAlarm7","_id":"59d50f49e877251d1eea592d"} 
Number of JSON entries not equal for element: '$.', expected '1' but was '4'
```

Any idea how to resolve it?

Regards
Geeks

Comment: Next time please take the time and put your code snippets in code blocks so they are readable, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting. This helps a lot in understanding problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your actual Json message has multiple elements (`__v`, `minVal`, `alarmName` and `_id`). Your control Json message just defines the element `alarmName`. Citrus Json message validator is using this strict mode by default so it will count and check that all elements are defined in expected control Json message. This is why you get the error.

Two options here. Either add all missing elements in control Json message with `@ignore@` value or disable strict mode in Json message validator. Second option can be done by overwriting the Json message validator bean:

```
<bean id="defaultJsonMessageValidator" class="com.consol.citrus.validation.json.JsonTextMessageValidator">
  <property name="strict" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: What about using JPath?

Comment: @gucce actually a good point! this option did not come to my mind in the first place totally valid option though. Instead of using a control message payload you could just use a validation JsonPath expression with `validate("$.alarmName", "@variable('apiVersion')@")`